# useState breaks application on added object in array

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react.

in one of the examples I pass an array of objects (id, title, amount, date) and use map to explode it into the visual code.
Each item is ExpenseItem and all items are written to screen.

Original code works as expected:

```
    function ExpenseItem(props) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setTitle('Updated!');
  };
  
  return (
    <Card className="expense-item">
      
      <ExpenseDate date={props.date}></ExpenseDate>
      <div className="expense-item__description">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="expense-item__price">
        {props.amount}
      </div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change Title</button>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

but - if I add to that original array another object dynamically
This code breaks and the title value for the added object is wrong and to other objects as well.

The easy fix is:

```
return (
    <Card className="expense-item">
      
      <ExpenseDate date={props.date}></ExpenseDate>
      <div className="expense-item__description">
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="expense-item__price">
        {props.amount}
      </div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change Title</button>
    </Card>
  );
```

but with this fix the button looses it's ability to change the title.

Any ideas why the first code doesn't work with the added ExpenseItem in the array ?

the parent component code:

```
return (
      
    <div>
      
      <Card className="expenses">
      <ExpensesFilter selected={filteredYear} onFilterChanged={filterChangedHandler} />
      {props.myExpenses.map((expense) => (<ExpenseItem
          title={expense.title}
          amount={expense.amount}
          date={expense.date}
        ></ExpenseItem>))}
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

and props.myExpenses holds the array of the 4 initial expenses and the newly added one.

Comment: your question is unclear. please provide some more information.

Comment: could you also share how you are adding an object to the original array dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had to read the next chapter of the course.
React can't handle updating the array of elements with state correctly unless a key is added.

The solution is to have a unique key to each item (which I have) and add it to the list:

```
return (
      
    <div>
      
      <Card className="expenses">
      <ExpensesFilter selected={filteredYear} onFilterChanged={filterChangedHandler} />
      {props.myExpenses.map((expense) => (<ExpenseItem
          key={expense.id}
          title={expense.title}
          amount={expense.amount}
          date={expense.date}
        ></ExpenseItem>))}
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

This solves the issue !